# security implications of Java's System.load vs System.loadLibrary

Tags: java, library

Jumping from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016391/difference-between-system-load-and-system-loadlibrary-in-java

What are the security implications of both approach ?

- `System.loadLibrary("_name_");`

  - Automatically searches for a library named "`lib_name_.so`" in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `System.load("/PATH/TO/_name_.so");`

  - do load "`/PATH/TO/_name_.so`"

Comment: You've mentioned `loadLibrary` two times. Shouldn't the second one be `System.load`?

Comment: Correct ! I'm editing right now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.loadLibrary()` refuses to load "libraries" with the path separator appearing in the name; see this excerpt from Java's source code (in `java.lang.Runtime.java`):

```
synchronized void loadLibrary0(Class fromClass, String libname) {
    SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (security != null) {
        security.checkLink(libname);
    }
    if (libname.indexOf((int)File.separatorChar) != -1) {
        throw new UnsatisfiedLinkError(
"Directory separator should not appear in library name: " + libname);
    }
    ClassLoader.loadLibrary(fromClass, libname, false);
}
```

As such, you *could* imagine allowing `System.loadLibrary()` but rejecting `System.load()`, giving access to only a specific set of loadable "safe" libraries... however, this seems indirect and fragile. The "normal" way of restricting native code loading is through [SystemManager.checkLink()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkLink%28java.lang.String%29), which is called from both `System.load()` and `System.loadLibrary()`. In that case, there is no real difference in security between the two methods.

Answer (score 6):

Relying on the calling system to help locate things can certainly lead down odd paths. The biggest problem is that the system may provide a file that wasn't intended to be loaded by the application. If an attacker can place a file in a location that falls under the search, then the attacker can inject arbitrary code into the application and execute it. E.g. an arbitrary code execution vulnerability

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution).
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/114.html

If you specify the exact path, you have the ability to protect the loaded file through things like file permissions, etc.

Comment: extra question : what if the library path has to be passed by command line ? I have to replace a failing autodiscovery mecanism and, following the KISS principle, would tend to use `System.load(..)` with the full path provided by the command line at runtime

Comment: Regarding "lead down odd paths", what if you'd already have `SystemManager.checkLink` properly implemented?